# issues with configuration and deployment of my app

Tags: bash, deployment, capistrano

I tried restarting my server some days ago with `sudo service httpd restart` and all sorts of problems have started happening.

I still log into my VPS server with `ssh myapp.com`.
I enter my password.
But then this comes up, which usen't to happen :

```
Last login: Sun Jul 21 22:54:02 2013 from 123.145-678-89.dsl.completel.net
-bash: __rvm_add_to_path: command not found
```

In Terminal I tried some things which solved problems for me before like:

```
bundle exec rake db:seed
```

But I keep getting:

```
-bash: bundle: command not found
```

Any idea how I can solve this problem? From what I've read it's suggested I look at my bash_profile/bashrc files and edit some things in there. But where are these located? What should I change? Where can I find my deploy log and configuration?

When I do a `cap production deploy:migrations` to transfer my site online to my remote server it all used to go fine, but now I get the error:

```
failed: "rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm/ $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'ree-1.8.7-2012.02' -c 'cd /var/www/apps/myapp/releases/20130720123042 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile'" on 12.34.567.8
mypc@ubuntu:~/myapp$
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling RVM with `\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable` sorted it out...